# How can I set the number of compiling workers (threads) in eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, compilation, xilinx, worker

I want to reduce my Xilinx-SDK (eclipse) C project compile time. I realized that the compilation uses only **one thread** on my multi-core PC. Where can I set **multi-worker compilation**?

Comment: Try this hint - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15608.html

Answer (score 0):

Right click the application project and go to its properties.
Under the "C/C++ Build" section go to the Behavior tab, there you can Enable parallel build settings. As shown in the figure.
[image: Properties]